# How do I poof this Poisson distribution problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have the following task.
But first: The task is not a homework assignment, its just for me, I'm not a student yet.

Task :

The number of students attending a stochastic for computer scientists consultation is poisson-distributed with parameters $\lambda > 0$.
These students each independently study computer science with probability $p$, where $p \in (0, 1)$.

Let $X$ be the number of computer science students attending office hours, and let $Y$ be the one
Number of students who are office hours visit but not computer science students.
Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
You can use, if necessary:

1: $\mathbb{P}(X=k | Y=n)=\left( \begin{array}{c}{n} \\ {k}\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$

2: $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^{k} p^{k}}{k !}$

My Idea:

The problem is simple but hart to prof formal(for me and thats why I need help).

The intersection of the event sets of X and Y is empty. Because there can not be a listener in the lecture who fulfills both results at the same time:

X: Attends the lecture and is a computer scientist.

Y: Attends the lecture and is not a computer scientist.

Could you help/show me how to make the a formal proof?

P.S. I hope I did not use the wrong tags. I could not find somthink better than Proof-writing . I'm so sorry.

Comment: No one has an idea?

Comment: $X$ is a random variable, not a set.  Do the calculations!

Comment: @user10354138    Hello, I tried for over 2 days but  I'm not able to find a real solution. But i think I have to use the   Process of Thinning a Poisson distribution. I know the formula, but i can not find a proof. That's why I'm here.
I tried to proof it with $$
P(X=k \wedge Y=n)=P(X=k) \cdot P(Y=n)
$$

Comment: One of your problems may be that both of the equation you "can use if necessary" appear to be wrong.  If I have understood your description correctly (of which I'm admittedly by no means certain), the first should be $\mathbb{P}(X=k |X+Y=n)=\left( \begin{array}{c}{n} \\ {k}\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$, and the second should be  $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^{k} p^{k}}{k !} e^{-\lambda p}\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Be certain.  That *is* indeed what they should be.  $X$ is the count for CS students in attendance, $Y$ is the count for non-CS students, so $X+Y$ is the count for total students in attendance (which is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$) Then$${X+Y\sim\mathcal {Pois}(\lambda)\\(X\mid X+Y=n)\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p)\\X\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda p)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the conditions described, as  I understand them:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}\left(X=k, Y=j\right) &=& \frac{\lambda^{k+j}}{\left(k+j\right)!}e^{-
\lambda}{k+j \choose k}p^k\left(1-p\right)^j\\
&=& \frac{\left(
\lambda p\right)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda p}\frac{\left(
\lambda \left(1-p\right)\right)^{\,j}}{j!}e^{-\lambda \left(1-p\right)}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
Summing this equation separately over $\ j\ $ and over $\ k\ $ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}\left(X=k\right) &=&  \frac{\left(
\lambda p\right)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda p}\ ,\mbox{ and}\\
\mathbb{P}\left(Y=j\right) &=& \frac{\left(
\lambda \left(1-p\right)\right)^{\,j}}{j!}e^{-\lambda \left(1-p\right)}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
Combining these results gives $\ \mathbb{P}\left(X=k, Y=j\right)= $$\mathbb{P}\left(X=k\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=j\right)\ $ for all $\ k\ $ and $\ j\ $, which thus establishes the independence of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $.